# Update missing values in MySQL 5.6 table by selecting values from closest records with same id

Tags: mysql, self-join, mysql-5.6, derived-table

Let's say I have a table with logs. The value of `status` column may be NULL and I would like to UPDATE this value by copying value from the log for same `settingid` which have non-NULL `status` and closest (smaller or equal) `mtime`.

| logid | settingid | status | mtime |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | 2022-10-01 | # NULL -> INACTIVE default |
| 2 | 1 | ACTIVE | 2022-10-02 |  |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | 2022-10-03 | # ACTIVE from 2 |
| 4 | 1 | NULL | 2022-10-04 | # ACTIVE from 2 |
| 5 | 1 | INACTIVE | 2022-10-05 |  |
| 6 | 1 | ACTIVE | 2022-10-06 |  |
| 7 | 1 | INACTIVE | 2022-10-07 |  |
| 8 | 1 | NULL | 2022-10-07 | # INACTIVE from 7 |
| 9 | 1 | NULL | 2022-10-09 | # INACTIVE from 7 |
| 10 | 2 | ACTIVE | 2022-10-10 |  |
| 11 | 2 | NULL | 2022-10-11 | # ACTIVE from 10 |

I have UPDATE query that works in MySQL 8 but how can I make it work in MySQL 5.6?

```
 WITH cte AS (
     SELECT
           logid,
           status,
           mtime,
           CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN
               IFNULL(
                   (
                       SELECT status
                       FROM logs
                       WHERE
                           settingid = t.settingid
                           AND status IS NOT NULL
                           AND mtime <= t.mtime
                           ORDER BY mtime DESC
                           LIMIT 1
                   ),
                   'INACTIVE'
               ) ELSE status END AS new_status
       FROM
           logs t
       ORDER BY mtime
   )
   UPDATE logs t LEFT JOIN cte USING (logid)
   SET t.status = cte.new_status
   WHERE t.status IS NULL;
```

Comment: @Akina There is really no benefit in changing to a markdown format table, because the table should be given as initialization code (aligned in columns) for a [mre] and not given as an ascii or markdown format table. The edit just promotes misconceptions & bad posts for the poster.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a nested subquery to select the closest record with a non-NULL status

```
UPDATE logs t
SET t.status = (
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(l.status), 'INACTIVE')
    FROM logs l
    WHERE l.settingid = t.settingid
    AND l.status IS NOT NULL
    AND l.mtime <= t.mtime
)
WHERE t.status IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make it work in MySQL 5.6?

Use user-defined variables.

```
UPDATE test
SET status = CASE WHEN status IS NOT NULL      THEN (@status := status)
                  WHEN settingid <> @settingid THEN (@status := 'INACTIVE')
                  ELSE                              @status
                  END,
    settingid = (@settingid := settingid)
WHERE (@status := '') IS NOT NULL
  AND (@settingid := 0) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY settingid, mtime;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/FaKFbYSJ

PS. This works in 8.0 too producing a lot of warning 1287.